# Matplotlib: boxplot stops programme execution

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, boxplot

I coded a small programme to reads in a CSV file and from its contents attempts to save a boxplot to a file:

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

data = pd.read_csv('Data.csv')

plt.ioff()
fig1, ax1 = plt.subplots()
ax1.set_title('Test Plot')
ax1.boxplot(data)
fig1.savefig('testGraph.pdf')   # save the figure to file
plt.close(fig1, bbox_inches='tight')
```

The contents of the `Data.csv` file look like:

```
"VarA","VarB"
"0.17930210790378986","886.9933011822859"
"0.01364054450557276","1139.6074779392254"
"0.17926365089066673","887.0276399462234"
"0.013813899304885247","1139.5782227339264"
"0.3265506417295615","2403.651444000035"
"0.5276772326905425","550.0787718046192"
"0.3266505322109829","2403.473910859639"
"0.5270364628724318","550.3655399414718"
"0.301951691229673","2447.2094472630693"
"0.5592257235158642","536.8017995252469"
"0.3020484011262961","2447.0390369668467"
"0.5584914299935637","537.1205945626922"
"0.2778648677077672","2489.339898509246"
"0.5928427006170575","523.2229700948385"
"0.2779586849926319","2489.177223805282"
"0.5919947811607554","523.5775073154801"
"0.2542483867446956","2529.825433671251"
"0.6287276395737614","509.40461834459865"
"0.2543395881647406","2529.6710855743004"
"0.6277398978255627","509.7994161108826"
```

Either through the interactive console, or feeding directly the code to the interpreter, execution halts at the `ax1.boxplot(data)` line, without any error messages shown or exceptions thrown. Example in the console:

```
$ python3
Python 3.6.7 (default, Oct 22 2018, 11:32:17)
[GCC 8.2.0] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.

>>> import pandas as pd
>>> import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
>>> hammer = pd.read_csv('Hammer.csv')
>>> plt.ioff()
>>> fig1, ax1 = plt.subplots()
>>> ax1.set_title('Basic Plot')
Text(0.5,1,'Basic Plot')
>>> ax1.boxplot(hammer)
```

After which the console becomes unresponsive. If I kill the console an exception is thrown, but it does not clarify the reason of the halt:

```
^CTraceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/matplotlib/__init__.py", line 1718, in inner
    return func(ax, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/matplotlib/axes/_axes.py", line 3378, in boxplot
    manage_xticks=manage_xticks, zorder=zorder)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/matplotlib/axes/_axes.py", line 3730, in bxp
    boxes.extend(doplot(box_x, box_y, **final_boxprops))
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/matplotlib/axes/_axes.py", line 3648, in doplot
    return self.plot(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/matplotlib/__init__.py", line 1718, in inner
    return func(ax, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/matplotlib/axes/_axes.py", line 1376, in plot
    self.autoscale_view(scalex=scalex, scaley=scaley)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/matplotlib/axes/_base.py", line 2280, in autoscale_view
    y_stickies = sum([sticky.y for sticky in stickies], [])
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/matplotlib/axes/_base.py", line 2280, in <listcomp>
    y_stickies = sum([sticky.y for sticky in stickies], [])
KeyboardInterrupt
```

What is preventing the full execution of the programme? Or the issuing of error messages?

Comment: @ImportanceOfBeingErnest you are correct, the values from the CSV must be transformed to numbers before being plotted. Could you please file your comment as an answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I could imagine that you haven't converted your strings to numbers, such that boxplots tries to do statistics on strings and will take forever to do so.

You can try

```
ax1.boxplot(hammer.values.astype(float))
```

Answer (score 0):

i took your init code with minor changes and it worked..

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt


def main():
    hammer = pd.read_csv('data.csv')

    plt.ioff()
    fig1, ax1 = plt.subplots()
    ax1.set_title('Test Plot')
    ax1.boxplot(hammer)
    fig1.savefig('testGraph.pdf')   # save the figure to file
    plt.close(fig1)


if __name__ == '__main__': main()
```

i was testing it on python 3.7
also , im running it on windows machine and not a linux one

Comment: This example also gets blocked at the `ax1.boxplot(hammer)` instruction. There were indeed some issues in the snippet, which admittedly was not tested. But the example in the interactive console was originally correct.